# Rails 3.1: Update Div with Link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's what I have:

```
<%= link_to "Reload Div", {:controller => "my_controller", :action => "my_action"}, remote => true %>
```

I want to be able to click the link and have a div reload with different content generated by Ruby on Rails. How can I do this?

For simplicity... I simply want to be able to click the link and reload the div with a number one higher than the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, this might be easier with UJS than by hacking something together yourself. Maybe something that does this:

```
$('a.reload').click(function() { $(this.parentNode).load(this.href); return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

If rails is incrementing the number, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use link_to as you have specified in your question as you have everything set up correctly with your controller, action, and the remote attribute.

Here is your action:

```
def my_action
  @counter = 1 #Insert whatever logic you need to increment the number.
end
```

Here is your view (my_action.js.erb):

```
$("#divtoreload").html("<%= @counter %>");
```